# Half Width and Full Width

Tags: c#

i want to do a software for japan.
it has a reqirment to control the full width and half width in a textbox.

if i set the control's width is full width, whatever typed text is "full-width".
and if i set the control's width is half width, whatever typed text is half-width".

how can i implement it?

thanks!

Comment: Is this a WPF, winforms, ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the VisualBasic class **Strings**. *Strings.StrConv* is for converting from half width characters to full width characters or other conversions.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.strconv.aspx)